# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'playercount' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, variables

Self explanatory, when i run this it gives me the error shown in the title even though I have assigned the variable playercount as a global before. What is it that I'm messing up here?

```
import discord
import asyncio
import mysql.connector
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host='no',
  database='no',
  user='no',
  password='no'
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()


client = Bot('!')
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('===========')
  print('Bot running')
  print('===========')

global playercount
playercount = 0

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content == '?help':
    helpMessage = discord.Embed(title="""Use ?joingame to join the game and follow instructions 
given.""")
    await message.channel.send(embed=helpMessage)

  if message.content == '?joingame':
   playercount = playercount + 1
   player = message.author.id
   add_player = "INSERT INTO user_info (userNum, UserId) VALUES (" + str(playercount) + ", " + 
str(player) + ")"
   cursor.execute(add_player)
   next_player = "SELECT userNum FROM user_info"
   cursor.execute(next_player)
   numberPlay = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
   print(numberPlay)
```

Comment: You need to add `global playercount` in your on_message function to let it know that your talking about the global one and not a locally scoped one

Comment: @ChrisDoyle This removed the error but now everytime I use the command ?joingame the var resets to 1

Answer (score 0):

`playercount` is the global variable. That means from a function, you can only read it not modify it. The way to change it is to use `global` keyword inside the function.

As for why the counter always reset to 0, that might be because when your application is launched, it launchs more than 1 instance. So you need to write that value into a filetext(txt or csv) or database.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
global playercount
playercount = 0
```

The Problem Lies In This Line as the variable is outside the function so it dont need to be declared global
Remove That Global Line and run the code